# Get next element from Query after element with specified Id. The LINQ expression could not be translated

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to make sure that after a certain sorting, I get the element that is after the current one in Query, using the current ID as an input parameter. I`am using EF Core and trying to build a query like this:

```
int id = {any id from input}

var result = query.OrderByDescending(x => somelist.Contains(a.Id))
.ThenByDescending(x => x.Date).SkipWhile(x => x.Id == id).ElementAt(1);
```

but got following error

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet() ... could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated

How can it be rewritten?

##### General description of query

Find an element by id and return its *successor* according to a specific ordering.

Comment: SkipWhile is not translatable to the SQL. Better write working SQL first then translate to LINQ.

Comment: Instead of `SkipWhile()` you could try `Where(x => x.Id != id).First()`

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride i need to get next element after element with specified Id, in sorted query, there are many elements. i do not need just an element with different id

Comment: I don't see how `Where()` and `First()` do something different than what you are asking, but an alternative might be to load everything into RAM and then do the selection: `.ThenByDescending(...).AsEnumerable().SkipWhile(...).ElementAt(1)`. This of course is not a good idea, if the part of the query before `AsEnumerable()` returns too many elements.

Comment: @Mateech In that case, xou could try `Where(x => x.Id != id).ElementAt(1)`.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Ok, I got it, my query has been wrong with `skipwhile`, I need to get next element from query after element with specified id, good if without using RAM

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride `Where` will remove all non-matching items from the result. `SkipWhile` skips items until the first item that doesn't match, but the remaining "tail" sequence may still contain non-matching items, because they won't be evaluated any more. So `Where` will only be yield the same result if the ordering matches the `SkipWhile` condition.

Comment: Since you say *My query is wrong, basic problem is getting element from query, after element with specified Id.*, could you show a valid case?

Comment: @GertArnold I thought `skipwhile` was a valid case, then they told me I am wrong, but as You said earlier `skipwhile` works as i need (skip elements until the first item doesnt match). If you got my question right you see what I`am trying to do. But my query cant be translated by EF Core. Can you give me an advice about it?

Comment: Your desciption is very confusing to me. Could you provide an example with an input list and what exactly you expect `result` to be?

Comment: @GertArnold, but `Where(x => x.Id != id)` doesn't mess with the ordering and the first element it returns will always be the first element where `Id` does not equal `id`. Since OP only wants this exact element, it shouldn't matter what elements will follow.

Comment: I still don't understand `.OrderByDescending(x => somelist.Contains(a.Id)` in which `x` is by no means used.

Comment: @snr I have a second table, and there are models with boolean property and foreign key to my main table that i build query for. I need to sort my query by boolean propery first from other table. Simply - There is just list of ids that should be in the beginning of query. Then i order by date. After all i need to find next element from query after element with `id` from input.

Comment: I finally understood what you are asking for. I edited the question with a description that might help future readers. Bad news is that `SkipWhile()` and `TakeUntil()` cannot be used in your scenario. Even in raw SQL this query is rather complicated, I guess. Have you considered using `AsEnumerable()`? If that's an option then the MoreLINQ function [`Pairwise()`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#pairwise) will make this trivial.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride In this case, MoreLINQ have another function called `SkipUntil` and it sounds like what I'am looking for.

Comment: Actually I misunderstood `SkipWhile()`. It will also work like you tried in combination with `ElementAt()` (as long as it is run in memory and not against the DB of course).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand question correctly, you need the following query:

```cs
var previousIds = ...

var result = query
    .OrderByDescending(x => somelist.Contains(a.Id))
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.Date)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Id)
    .Where(x => !previousIds.Contains(x.Id))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It looks closer, but isn`t it break my sorting? I dont need query sort by Id

Comment: It will not break your sorting. But I think you need to sort by id because we use greater than operator.

Comment: See my comment below the question. `SkipWhile` is really a different operation. It depends on sort order if it returns the same results as `Where`. Since `Date` is the first ordering here, the results will very likely differ. Doing the same thing in SQL requires more than a simple SQL statement that EF could be made to generate.

Comment: @GertArnold, rethinking your comment and I still think that this query will return correct result. It will return First not ID with correct ordering.

Comment: Doesnt work as I need. Is it possible because my Id not `integer` format but `string(guid)`?
I got error `System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements`

Comment: `somelist` has no elements or you have changed `FirstOrDefault`  to `First`?

Comment: @Mateech, try to change `.Where(x => x.Id != id)`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv it closer, but still not the goal. I changed as you said and now when i send an id of element that is first in query to input, i got next element as i need. But when i send id of this second element, i got my first element back again as result (instead of 3rd).

Comment: That's why i have added ordering by Id. For which purpose added this one `.OrderByDescending(x => somelist.Contains(a.Id))`?

Comment: I have a second table, and there are models with boolean property and foreign key to my main table that i build query for. I need to sort my query by boolean propery from other table

Comment: So you have to filter out previous Ids.

Comment: That's why I tried to use `SkipWhile` but it cant be translated. Dont know how to rewrite it without

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234524/discussion-between-mateech-and-svyatoslav-danyliv).